# When exactly does an attacking creature become tapped?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I have a creature on the board, which is eligible to attack, however my opponent has enchanted it with [Brink of Disaster](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=244246). Now as I attack with the creature, does it first become tapped (and will therefore be destroyed) or does it first deal damage?
And in case it becomes tapped before dealing damage, does it become tapped before the opponent declares blockers or after?
When exactly during the action of attacking does the attacking creature become tapped?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The attacker becomes tapped during the Declare Attackers step.  The steps of combat are:

1. Beginning of Combat
2. Declare Attackers
3. Declare Blockers
4. Damage Resolution
5. End of Combat

So, since the attacker becomes tapped during step 2, it is destroyed before step 4 where it would normally deal damage.

For a full breakdown of a turn, see [this post](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/20861/10354)